# upgrade from symfony 2.0 to 2.3

Tags: symfony, upgrade, symfony-2.3

I already have running project which is in `Symfony 2.0.10`. But now I need to upgrade it to `Symfony 2.3`.I know there is need to change some code to compitable with latest version.Is there any command to upgrade? Or what is the exact procedure to upgrade? Is there any document available?.

**Edit:**

I put `symfony 2.3` `composer.json` file and while doing `php composer.phar update` I got this error.

```
Problem 1
    - symfony/symfony v2.3.1 requires symfony/icu >=1.0,<2.0 -> no matching package found.
    - symfony/symfony v2.3.0 requires symfony/icu >=1.0,<2.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.3.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.3.1].
```

**Edit 2:**
First I got this error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                
  The dist file "app/config/parameters.yml.dist" does not exist. Check your dist-file config or create it.
```

so I created `parameters.yml.dist` file.
Now I'm getting

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader' not found in /var/www/git/sample/app/autoload.php on line 6
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

  [RuntimeException]                                     
  An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file.
```

Comment: your edit introduced a new question :) edit symfony/icu to use @beta compatibility flag.`"require": {"symfony/intl": "2.3.*@beta" }` ... related to this issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8035

Comment: Sorry:).I solved this issue by adding in composer.json file "symfony/intl": "2.3.*"

Comment: great any other problems? otherwise you might want to upvote/accept one of the answers as the original question has been answered by me and pazi :)

Comment: My upgrade still didn't finish.I'm getting one more problem.Ill update that also:)

Comment: I solved issue by copying autoload.php from Symfony 2.3 autoload.php

Comment: i am getting 
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader' not found in D:\www\o2l\app\autoload.php on line


what is the problem please reply

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Upgrade information**

Read the upgrade guides in [symfony/symfony github repository](https://github.com/symfony/symfony):

- [Upgrade 2.1](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/UPGRADE-2.1.md)
- [Upgrade 2.2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/UPGRADE-2.2.md)
- [Upgrade 2.3](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/UPGRADE-2.3.md)
- [Upgrade 2.4](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/UPGRADE-2.4.md)
- [Upgrade 2.5](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/UPGRADE-2.5.md)
- [Upgrade 2.6](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/UPGRADE-2.6.md)
- [Upgrade 2.7](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/UPGRADE-2.7.md)
- [Upgrade 3.0](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/UPGRADE-3.0.md)

There are also changelogs in the repository:

- [CHANGELOG-2.2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/CHANGELOG-2.2.md)
- [CHANGELOG-2.3](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/CHANGELOG-2.3.md)

Backup your project!

---

**Upgrading with composer**

Get [composer](http://getcomposer.org/download/) and put the **symfony 2.3 standard edition's [composer.json](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.3/composer.json)** into your project root.

Now run `composer update` with your project's patch as working directory.

-> You will face some exceptions due to breaking changes exceptions. Google will help resolve those :)

---

**Personal experience**

In my legacy projects the most noticeable bc break from 2.0 to 2.1 was [this one](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md#bc-breaks-in-form-types-and-options) related to the form-builder because I had to update every form.

Before ( 2.0 )

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
```

After ( 2.1+ )

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
```

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading is in general simple, as you only have to update the version constraints in your composer.json according to the [standard distribution](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v2.3.1/composer.json) and issuing

```
php composer.phar update
```

But 2.3 has some backwards compatibility breaks. So read carefully every upgrade document for necessary code changes.

- [from 2.0 to 2.1](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v2.3.1/UPGRADE.md)
- [from 2.1 to 2.2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v2.3.1/UPGRADE-2.2.md)
- [from 2.2 to 2.3](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.3/UPGRADE-2.3.md)

Comment: What a mess.  I'm not sure that dealing with the added complexity of Sf2 is worth the productivity benefit.

Comment: What, that's normal, when you skip two major versions. Only since 2.3 with the new release schedule no bc breaks should occur with 2.x versions.

Comment: Symfony 2.0 didn't use composer ;)